# Value is not an array ref error

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

I have a list of checkboxes. I am trying to pass the list of selected checkboxes to a perl script. I am obtaining the list of checkboxes using the folliwng code :

```
function exec(){
    var checkedValue = "";  
    var inputElements = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
    for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; i++){ 
      if(inputElements[i].className==="chk" &&  
         inputElements[i].checked){ 
           checkedValue += inputElements[i].value;
           if (inputElements[i+1])
               checkedValue += ", ";
           else
               checkedValue += "";  
      } 
    }
```

I am then passing "checkedValue" to a perl script as follows :

```
self.location='/cgi-bin/ATMRunJob.pl?tcs='+checkedValue;
```

In the perl script, I read the array as follows :

```
our @testCasesToRun = $var->param("tcs");
```

This is then assigned to a hash as follows :

```
my $runSpec = {

         TestCasesToRun    => @testCasesToRun
      };
```

However, I get the following error when I load the page in the browser :

```
Failed TestLimits() with error: [hash: k=TestCasesToRun, v=1,]:[array]:Value is not an array ref
In check against following TLS:
[
  'hr',
  {
    'OptDefaults' => {
      'JobRunningGroupName' => 'astbluetooth',
      'RunMode' => 'Queue',
      'CountTowardsReporting' => 1,
      'JobOwnerGroupName' => 'astbluetooth',
      'SelectSetupTeardown' => 1
    },
    'Optional' => {
      'TestCasesToRun' => [
        'ar',
        undef,
        undef,
        [
          'r',
          1,
          undef
        ]
      ],
```

I am new to perl as well as CGI scripting. How could I get around this error?

NOTE : All the code snippets have been shortened for brevity, but still portray the essence of the problem.

EDIT : What I want to do is this. The user selects a list of test cases from a checkboxed list that he wants to execute. I take the test case ids of all the selected test cases and pass it to a perl script. In the perl script, I just need to assign these selected testcase ids to the TestCasesToRun element in the runspec hash.

What would be the correct way to do that?

Comment: What happens after `$runSpec`? Where is `TestLimits`?

Comment: Not biting you right now but could: `@testCasesToRun` should not be an array, or `$runSpec` hash will be messed up.

Comment: And what are the input values? I.e. exactly what gets submitted?

Comment: The test case ids are integers. So the problem basically is assigning an integer array from php to an integer array in perl.

Comment: Please clarify all the points, not just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are assigning an array as a hashkey value. That doesn't work; you need to assign an array ref:

   ```
    my $runSpec = {
        TestCasesToRun    => \@testCasesToRun
    };
   ```

   Given that the code compiles, I have a feeling you just messed up your examples in the Q - please fix them to **accurately** reflect your code, even if they will be slightly less brief.
2. Your 'tcs' parameter is a single string (assigned via JS). Why are you then assigning results of param('tcs') to an array in the first place? Do you have a `split` somewhere in your code that you didn't include into the example?
3. Your dump contains an array reference within an array reference. You need to elaborate on what the expected structure of `TestCasesToRun` arrayref is, and show the code which processes it in the test runner.

As per your last comment:

- Change your JavaScript code to join using simple comma: `checkedValue += ",";`
- Change your Perl assignment to: `our @testCasesToRun = split(/,/, $var->param("tcs"));`

Comment: Judging from the JavaScript code, that array always contains a single value, so it might not be the cause.

Comment: @Koterpillar - that's the second issue

Comment: Interestingly, the error message shows a dump of a value where it _is_ an array reference.

Comment: @Koterpillar - what throws me MUCH more is hat array ref contains a SECOND arrayref.

Comment: Basically, this is just a comment, but too big to fit in comments. I can't answer till all 3 of these are addressed.

Comment: What I want to do is this. The user selects a list of test cases from a checkboxed list that he wants to execute. I take the test case ids of all the selected test cases and pass it to a perl script. In the perl script, I just need to assign these selected testcase ids to the **TestCasesToRun** element in the runspec hash.

What would be the correct way to do that?